# How to make record in two tabled

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, crud

How to make two record in table using JPA and Hibernate.
So I have relation between two tables person and user. Table user has column person_id. So first we need to make a record to person, get id and write to user table and make commit.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {
  @Column(name="id")
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  @Column(name="old_id", nullable = false)
  private String oldId

}


@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name="id")
  private long id;

  @Column(name="username")
  private String username;

  @Column(name="password")
  private String password;

  @Column(name="person_id")
  private long personId;

  public User(String username, String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
  }
personRepository.save(new Person("9999-1","Denis Beloff","Denis",
                "Beloff", LocalDate.now(),LocalDate.now(),"M",33,
                174.0,83.1,"Some Street",LocalDate.now(),"some@email.com",
                "890327388", new User("some@email.com", "passw")));
```

Comment: Where is the DAO method that you are supposed to use for saving?

Comment: its provided by CrudRepository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the code as it is you have to save first the Person and then get the id and set it to the Users personId field.

Otherwise you have to define a one to one relationship from person to user with cascading when persisting:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Person person.
```

And then you can set the person on the User class and everything will be inserted by Hibernate.

Comment: No, I don't want to keep the code as it is. i'm trying to find a correct way. So if u have some examples or references it would be great.

Comment: So my suggested solution with OneToOne mapping is what you are looking for. For further information you should read the Hibernate Manual https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html